# Eclipse Juno- WindowBuilder gives parsing Error(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, windowbuilder

Stack trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.checkNewChild(ASTNode.java:1901)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList.add(ASTNode.java:1269)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.ast.AstEditor.addStatement(AstEditor.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.generation.statement.AbstractInsideStatementGenerator.add(AbstractInsideStatementGenerator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.generation.statement.flat.FlatStatementGenerator.add(FlatStatementGenerator.java:66)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.add(JavaInfoUtils.java:1386)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.add(JavaInfoUtils.java:1289)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.add(JavaInfoUtils.java:1225)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.layout.LayoutInfo.add(LayoutInfo.java:319)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.MigLayout.model.MigLayoutInfo.command_CREATE(MigLayoutInfo.java:797)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.MigLayout.gef.MigLayoutEditPolicy$2.executeEdit(MigLayoutEditPolicy.java:223)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.gef.command.EditCommand$1.run(EditCommand.java:52)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.run(ExecutionUtils.java:324)
at org.eclipse.wb.core.gef.command.EditCommand.execute(EditCommand.java:50)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.executeCommand(EditDomain.java:59)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.executeCommand(Tool.java:209)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.AbstractCreationTool.handleButtonUp(AbstractCreationTool.java:62)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.mouseUp(Tool.java:395)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.mouseUp(EditDomain.java:255)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.graphical.EditEventManager.mouseUp(EditEventManager.java:149)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager$8.invoke(EventManager.java:325)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.mouseUp(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I have been using WindowBuilder to Create the layout of the JFrame.I am using Eclipse Juno and I was putting JLabels and JTextFields in until I tried to put in another JTextField and got this error.When i restart eclipse then it works for some times and again gives same error,if anyone have solution then please give me some suggestion

Regards.

Comment: I can feel your pain, I tried WindowBuilder to reverse engineer some working code and it worked at first, only to crash seemingly at random when editing. If you don't have to use Eclipse, then NetBeans has a good integrated GUI designer (and is the official Oracle IDE).

Comment: But NetBeans not supported to MigLayout..thats why i used Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Well, you are right. You can [vote the ticket](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93370) for the implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code, I can only tell you to look this good hierarchy of WindowsBuilder. That derived from the others and ContentPane that is well structured.